# What is a good way to compute the value of sums of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+4)} $, for example?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I see it's similarities to the Dirichlet beta function, but I don't see the trick I need to use to manipulate it. I want it in terms of pi and the natural logarithm of something.

Comment: Maybe the $\;x\,'$s are $\;n\,'$s...?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake.

Comment: Partial fraction expansion for terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac1{(2n+1)(n+4)}=\frac17\left[\frac2{2n+1}-\frac1{n+4}\right],
$$
so that it essentially remains to evaluate the series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+4}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+4)}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2*(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+8)} $$

= $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{7}\frac{(-1)^n*((2n+8)-(2n+1))}{(2n+1)(2n+8)} $$

= $$\frac{2}{7} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n*((2n+8)-(2n+1))}{(2n+1)(2n+8)} $$

= $$\frac{2}{7} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} - \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+8)})$$

= $$\frac{2}{7} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} - \frac{2}{7} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+8)}$$

= $$\frac{2}{7} \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{7} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+4)}$$

= $$\frac{\pi}{14} + \frac{1}{7} (ln(1+1) - (1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}))$$

= $$\frac{\pi}{14} + \frac{1}{7} (\ln(2) - \frac{5}{6})$$

= $$\frac{1}{42}\left(3\pi + 6\ln(2) - 5\right)$$

Comment: What is $x$?  Don't you mean $\ln2$?

Comment: yes I meant ln(2). Thanks for pointing out